# How to use pyspark mllib RegressionMetrics with real predictions

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

With pyspark 1.4 I am trying to use RegressionMetrics() for predictions
generated by LinearRegressionWithSGD.

All examples for RegressionMetrics() given in [pyspark mllib documentations](http://people.apache.org/~pwendell/spark-releases/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html) are for "artificial" predictions and observations
like

```
predictionAndObservations = sc.parallelize([ (2.5, 3.0), (0.0, -0.5), (2.0, 2.0), (8.0, 7.0)])
```

For such "artificial" (generated with sc.parallelize) RDD everything works fine. However, when doing the same with another RDD generated in another way, I get

```
TypeError: DoubleType can not accept object in type <type 'numpy.float64'>
```

The short reproducible example is below.

What can be the problem?

```py
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LinearRegressionWithSGD, LinearRegressionModel
from pyspark.mllib.evaluation import RegressionMetrics

dataRDD = sc.parallelize([LabeledPoint(1, [1,1]), LabeledPoint(2, [2,2]), LabeledPoint(3, [3,3])])
lrModel = LinearRegressionWithSGD.train(dataRDD)
prediObserRDD = dataRDD.map(lambda p: (lrModel.predict(p.features), p.label)).cache()
```

Let us check that RDD is indeed of (prediction, observation) pairs

```
prediObserRDD.take(4) # looks OK
```

Now try to calculate metrics

```
metrics = RegressionMetrics(prediObserRDD)
```

It gives the following error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-ca9ad8e9faf1> in <module>()
      7 prediObserRDD = dataRDD.map(lambda p: (lrModel.predict(p.features), p.label)).cache()
      8 prediObserRDD.take(4)
----> 9 metrics = RegressionMetrics(prediObserRDD)
     10 #metrics.explainedVariance
     11 #metrics.meanAbsoluteError

/usr/local/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/mllib/evaluation.py in __init__(self, predictionAndObservations)
     99         df = sql_ctx.createDataFrame(predictionAndObservations, schema=StructType([
    100             StructField("prediction", DoubleType(), nullable=False),
--> 101             StructField("observation", DoubleType(), nullable=False)]))
    102         java_class = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.RegressionMetrics
    103         java_model = java_class(df._jdf)

/usr/local/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/sql/context.py in createDataFrame(self, data, schema, samplingRatio)
    337 
    338         for row in rows:
--> 339             _verify_type(row, schema)
    340 
    341         # convert python objects to sql data

/usr/local/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/sql/types.py in _verify_type(obj, dataType)
   1027                              "length of fields (%d)" % (len(obj), len(dataType.fields)))
   1028         for v, f in zip(obj, dataType.fields):
-> 1029             _verify_type(v, f.dataType)
   1030 
   1031 _cached_cls = weakref.WeakValueDictionary()

/usr/local/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/sql/types.py in _verify_type(obj, dataType)
   1011     if type(obj) not in _acceptable_types[_type]:
   1012         raise TypeError("%s can not accept object in type %s"
-> 1013                         % (dataType, type(obj)))
   1014 
   1015     if isinstance(dataType, ArrayType):

TypeError: DoubleType can not accept object in type <type 'numpy.float64'>
```

The same problem also appears (for another dataset and classification task) with BinaryClassificationMetrics.

Comment: @eliasah Thanks to your comment, I found in SparkProgrammingGuide that DoubleWritable corresponds to python type "float". So I converted the values to float and everything works now. Please post your comment as answer so that I can accept it

Comment: By the way, this is pretty much unexpected behaviour of spark. DenseVector, for example, IS numpy array. It would be reasonable  to convert all numpy.float types to DoubleType automatically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like the error says `TypeError: DoubleType can not accept object in type <type 'numpy.float64'>`

You are trying to convert a `numpy.float64` into a Double which cannot be done.

To solve that TypeError, you'll have to convert your value to a accepted Type.

Example :

```
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LinearRegressionWithSGD, LinearRegressionModel
from pyspark.mllib.evaluation import RegressionMetrics

dataRDD = sc.parallelize([LabeledPoint(1, [1,1]), LabeledPoint(2, [2,2]), LabeledPoint(3, [3,3])])
lrModel = LinearRegressionWithSGD.train(dataRDD)
prediObserRDD = dataRDD.map(lambda p: (float(lrModel.predict(p.features)), p.label)).cache()
```

If you've noticed, I have converted the prediction label into a double using Python built-in `float` function.

Now you can compute your metrics :

```
>>> metrics = RegressionMetrics(prediObserRDD)
>>> metrics.explainedVariance
1.0
```